# Cannot convert string to unsigned long in C

Tags: c, type-conversion, strtoul

I convert string to unsigned long like this code.

```
String t = "1667451600";
unsigned long ret;
ret = strtoul(t,NULL,10);
```

It show error like this.

```
test:122:19: error: cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*'
  122 |     ret = strtoul(t,NULL,10);
      |                   ^
      |                   |
      |                   String

exit status 1
cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*'
```

How to canvert string to unsigned long in C ?

Comment: String is an object I'm guessing? , strtoul wants a char pointer. String isn't standard C. You should be able to access the char pointer directly inside the String object.

Comment: There is no `String` in standard C. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that details the type definition for `String` (or some documentation thereof).

Comment: From the error message this looks more like C++ than C.

Comment: Your question will get closed soon unless you explain what 'String' is or provide a complete small example of its being used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String` is not a standard type in C. Try this:

```
char *t = "1667451600";
unsigned long ret;
ret = strtoul(t,NULL,10);
```